# Есть ли в Node JavaScript библиотека, которая показывает диалоговое окно проводника (выбора файла)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Нужна библиотека, которая показывает **диалоговое окно проводника (выбора файла)** на **Node JS**. То есть, нужно окно выбора файла и когда мы выбрали файл, то в **переменную записывается абсолютный путь этого файла.**

Comment: Строка поиска на [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) + слова `file`, `open`, `dialog`.

Comment: Можно точнее, если не трудно?  Для ясности, есть просто файл program.js нужна библиотека, которая запускает этот файловый диалог.

Comment: Что именно требует уточний - как перейти по ссылке, или как нажать клавиши для ввода слов в строку поиска? Если затруднения с использованием клавиатуры, то [вот прямая ссылка](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=file%20open%20dialog) на результаты со всеми тремя ключевыми словами.

Comment: `node.js` вроде не про `gui`, ты из консоли проводник собрался вызывать?

Comment: Используя сторонние библиотеки, запустить подобие или сам проводник.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Запуск и результат

```
$ node src/open-file-dialog/index.js 
... выбор файлов в диалоге выбора файлов ...

[
  '/Users/nörbörnën/Work/apple-wallet/z/manifest.json',
  '/Users/nörbörnën/Work/apple-wallet/z/pass.json'
]
```

#### index.js

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');
const electronPath = require('electron');

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log(await filesSelection());
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();

async function filesSelection() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const child = spawn(`${electronPath}`, [path.join(__dirname, 'dialog.js')]);

    let out = '';
    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => out += data);
    child.stderr.on('data', reject);
    child.on('close', (code) => {
      try {
        if (code === 0) {
          return resolve(JSON.parse(out));
        }
        reject(new Error(`child process exited with code ${code}`));
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

#### dialog.js

```
const { app, dialog } = require('electron');

app.on('ready', async () => {
  try {
    const res = await dialog.showOpenDialog({
      properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
    });
    process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(res?.filePaths || []));
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```